# .apk file not installed programmatically

Tags: android, signature, android-install-apk

I want to .apk file which is new version on my app. install on Android device for upgrade;

But I get "Parse Error" or "App not installed"

*If I manually try install .apk file DELETE old version app. , it works*
*If I manually try install .apk file after debug old version app it does not work*

I tested on another different .apk file on my code it can be install so I do not think about that but here is it you can check;

```
 File fileTest = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/appName.apk");
    if (fileTest != null && fileTest.exists() == true){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/appName.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
```

This problem may be **Signature differ** or **Sdk versions differ**.
I tested signature differ with my code app and .apk file here it is;

```
 Signature sig = updateContext.getPackageManager().
           getPackageInfo(updateManager.updateContext.getPackageName(), 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];

Signature releaseSig = updateManager.updateContext.getPackageManager().
  getPackageArchiveInfo(path2, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[0];

String path2 =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
            "/download/appName.apk";

if (sig.hashCode() != releaseSig.hashCode()) //false
```

So what do you think about this?

Comment: I don't know for the SDK, but the signature has to be the same for the app to be replaced. I already had that problem with debug apps that were built on different computers (generated signature was different)

Comment: go to settings uninstall both apps (or) both user apps, in some phones have two or more user accounts remove those app also, and install app via debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

Two versions of an app signed by different keys can't be installed over each other.

Your debug version is signed automatically by a debug key that's present on your computer.

Your release version of the application is signed a key that you provide.

If you try to install release version of the app over debug version of the app then it will not work, you will first have to uninstall older version.

In real life usecase it should not be a problem since users will only have access to release version of the application(of course, if you don't send them debug version).

Comment: You say uninstall older version but when i debug old version .apk installed so what should i do? may i equalize my app signature with .apk when debugging.

Comment: No. Only install a debug version on top of a debug version app. Install new release version on top of old release version. Don't mix them.